# Any way to unload the pdb?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, pdb-files

Debugging app with VS2012, unload one dll in the code, the dll can be unloaded successfully, but the pdb file of the dll is still in process, I can't to delete/replace it. Any way to unload the pdb?

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: c++, I don't thinks it's related with language.

Comment: It is related.  This is a known problem in VS2012.  Also carried forward in VS2013, Update 2 has a fix, currently in CTP.  A possible workaround is Tools + Options, Debugging, General, turn on the "Managed C++ compatibility mode" checkbox.  This disables the new visualizers.

Comment: I'm using VS2012 with update 3. and "Managed C++ compatibility mode" checkbox is turned on. But still have the issue.